# How to generate a report for particular XHTML tag/attributes?

Tags: testing, xhtml, selenium, accessibility, automated-tests

I wan to check whole site's `<img>` image's for `alt` text. I want to get a report of, What is written in `alt` text or `alt` is defined or not from all images being used on whole site in every page.

Is it possible to get report like this? after getting report i will put `alt` or if `alt` is already added but blank, then will write description text.

Otherwise in a big site it will take huge time to go and check each page.

Site is on Intranet and accessible with username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but since it seems like your motivation here is just to know which `img` elements don't have alt attributes, I wanted to add that not **all** `img` elements need alt attributes.

The [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-img-alt) mentions which `img` elements should have alt attributes:

> What an img element represents depends on the src attribute and the alt attribute.
>
> > If the src attribute is set and the alt attribute is set to the empty string
> >
> > > - The image is either decorative or supplemental to the rest of the content, redundant with some other information in the document.
> > > - If the image is available and the user agent is configured to display that image, then the element represents the image specified by the src attribute.
> > > - Otherwise, the element represents nothing, and may be omitted completely from the rendering. User agents may provide the user with a notification that an image is present but has been omitted from the rendering.
> >
> > If the src attribute is set and the alt attribute is set to a value that isn't empty
> >
> > > - The image is a key part of the content; the alt attribute gives a textual equivalent or replacement for the image.
> > > - If the image is available and the user agent is configured to display that image, then the element represents the image specified by the src attribute.
> > > - Otherwise, the element represents the text given by the alt attribute. User agents may provide the user with a notification that an image is present but has been omitted from the rendering.
> >
> > If the src attribute is set and the alt attribute is not
> >
> > > - The image might be a key part of the content, and there is no textual equivalent of the image available.
> > > - *Note: In a conforming document, the absence of the alt attribute indicates that the image is a key part of the content but that a textual replacement for the image was not available when the image was generated.*
> > > - If the image is available, the element represents the image specified by the src attribute.
> >
> > If the src attribute is not set and either the alt attribute is set to the empty string or the alt attribute is not set at all
> >
> > > - The element represents nothing.
> >
> > Otherwise
> >
> > > - The element represents the text given by the alt attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with Selenium it will be something like this

```
Dictionary<string,string> details = new Dictionary<string,string>();
int imgcount = selenium.GetXpathCount("//img");
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  details.add(selenium.GetAttribute("//img[i]@src"),selenium.GetAttribute("//img[i]@alt"));
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in details)
{
   Console.WriteLine("key " + kvp.Key);
   Console.WriteLine("Value " + kvp.Value);
}
```

That will print the src of the image and its ALT text.

Comment: thnaks for answer. How to run this script on whole site using Selenium in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Using [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) I came up with this quick script:

```
GotoURL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570421/how-to-generate-a-report-for-particular-xhtml-tag-attributes

foreach %Image% in (response //img)
    set %src% as combineCurrentURL (selectIn %Image% @src)
    set %alt% as trim (selectIn %Image% @alt)

    if numComp 0 = (length %alt%)
        Notice %src% ALT IS EMPTY
    else
        Notice %src% : %alt%
    end
end
```

The output looks like below (a CSV report can also be generated if desired)

```
00000001-00 NOTICE http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png : Stack Overflow
00000002-00 NOTICE http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/ladywhobig.jpg ALT IS EMPTY
00000003-00 NOTICE http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-arrow-up.png : vote up
00000004-00 NOTICE http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-arrow-down.png : vote down
```

This works in both the HTMLUnit and Selenium backend to TestPlan.